# Does the word "chuunibyou" originate from the anime "Chuunibyou"?

Tags: japanese-language, love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

I was reading *Black Lagoon* and realized that Lotton is a bit like a chuunibyou. He called himself "The Wizard" and he always wanted to make a cool entrance before a fight but usually got his ass kicked quickly. In my opinion, he's a chuuninbyou. But no one ever mention that he's chuunibyou.

(Or probably he's not chuunibyou after all, but keep that for another question.)

Being the earlier anime (*Black Lagoon* was aired in 2006 while *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!* was aired in 2012) it got me thinking about whether the word "chuunibyou" actually originated from this anime. Or probably it was not just as popular as now.

Comment: Can't say it's the true origin, but I do know the slang "chuunibyou" has been used on the radio somewhere in 2000 iirc.

Comment: [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Chuunibyou) explains it better than I could.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the word "chuunibyou" was not coined by the anime *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!* (nor by *Black Lagoon*). The term is attested back to 1999. (For further reading, the [TVTropes article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Chuunibyou) linked in [Aki Tanaka's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44044/is-the-word-chuunibyou-originated-from-the-anime-chuuni#comment58985_44044) seems good.)

[Data from Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85,%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E6%81%8B%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) seem to indicate that searches for this word were low but slowly rising until October 2012, when searches spiked (because that's when *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!* premiered). Search volume for "chuunibyou" has since fallen off, but is somewhat higher than it was just before October 2012, even after you subtract out searches specifically for *Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!*. My point here is that in 2006 (unlike now), the word "chuunibyou" had very limited purchase and it is hence unsurprising that it would not be used in *Black Lagoon*.

Comment: Plus two more facts: 1) Black Lagoon's plot is set before 1999. 2) the only japanese guy in Black Lagoon is Rock.